# Matlab - How can I get the expression of the level curves of a function?

Tags: matlab, math, contour

I would like to obtain the **level curves** of a given function z=f(x,y) **without using the countours function** in the Matlab environment.

By letting Z equal to some constant 'c' we get a single level curve. I would like to *obtain an expression of the resulting function of the form y=f(x)* to be able to study other properties of it.

**Basic: Example 1: Easy game**

Let's consider the problem of plotting level curves of `z=-x^2-y^2+100` for x,y:-10;10 and z=1.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
Z = -X.^2+-(Y).^2+100;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

we obtain the following figure:

[image]

The countour function gives me what I was looking for:

```
h=[1,1]
contour(X,Y,Z,h)
```

I can get the same result by solving the equation with respect to x

```
syms x y;
soly = solve(1==-x.^2-y^2+100, y)
t=soly(1)
x=-10:0.1:10;
figure;
plot(x,(99-x.^2).^(1/2));
hold on
plot(x,-(99-x.^2).^(1/2));


soly =

  (99 - x^2)^(1/2)
 -(99 - x^2)^(1/2)
```

[image]

**The Problem: Example 2**

Let's consider the following 3D function.

[image]

This function is the sum of guassians with random centers, variances and peaks. You can get it with the following code:

```
%% Random Radial Basis functions in space 
disp('3D case with random path - 10 rbf:');
N = 10 % number of random functions
stepMesh = 0.1;
Z = zeros((XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+1,(XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(XMin:stepMesh:XMax);
% random variance in [a;b] = [0.3;1.5]
variances = 0.3 + (1.5-0.3).*rand(N,1);
% random amplitude [0.1;1]
amplitudes = 0.1 + (1-0.1).*rand(N,1);
% Random Xcenters in [-XMin;xMax]
Xcenters = XMin+ (XMax-XMin).*rand(N,1);
Ycenters = YMin+ (YMax-YMin).*rand(N,1);

esp=zeros(N,1);
esp=1./(2*(variances).^2);
for i=1:1:N
    disp('step:')
    disp(i)
    Xci=Xcenters(i,1)*ones((XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+1,((XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+1)*2);
    Yci=Ycenters(i,1)*ones((YMax-YMin)/stepMesh+1,((YMax-YMin)/stepMesh+1)*2);
    disp('Radial Basis Function: [amplitude,variance,center]');
    disp(amplitudes(i,1))
    disp(variances(i,1))
    disp(Xcenters(i,1))
    disp(Ycenters(i,1))
    Z = Z + 1*exp(-((X-Xci(:,1:((XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+1))).^2+(Y-Yci(:,((XMax-XMin)/stepMesh+2):((YMax-YMin)/stepMesh+1)*2)).^2)*esp(i,1).^2);
end
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

The countour3 function draws a contour plot of matrix Z in a 3-D view, which is really nice, but it doesn't give me the expression of these functions in 2D.

```
figure;
contour3(X,Y,Z);
grid on
box on
view([130,30])
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
zlabel('z-axis')
```

[image]

**The Question**:
How can I get an explicit expression of the level curves of the second example?

Comment: You cannot solve any type of equation ... to me it looks like this is not possible in the general case, and I don'y see how you could find these contours other than numerically. For instance the number of objects will change for every drawing, which adds a layer of complexity. Why do you assume that this is feasible ?

Comment: Seconding Ratbert, this can be done sometimes, but not generally. Moreover, it is not a programming but a math problem. I'd recommend you ask about a specific function you're interested in, on math.SE.

Comment: @Ratbert: I wasn't sure, that's why I asked. So the only way to solve this problem, is to consider the numerical approach.
Is there a way to get a bidimensional array of the points for which the value of the function is greater than a threshold?

Comment: Have a look at `contour`.

Comment: I'll do it. I thought there was a function for this...